# Why Does my Keyboard have the Pound Sign When It's the Hash tag Sign?

Tags: settings

Every time I try to hit my # Sign on my Raspberry Pi it comes out as the Pound sign, I've been using the settings but nothing seems to work. How can I solve this problem

Comment: You need to change the keyboard settings see this question http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26585/remapping-keyboard