# How to type hash ('#') in the boot config

Tags: keyboard

I'm trying to edit the `config.txt` at the NOOBS boot menu.

This file format comments out lines by putting `#` at the start. How do I type that character?  (Typing it normally on my keyboard generates the old UK currency symbol).

Note: I have already done the solution in [Remapping keyboard](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26585/remapping-keyboard); it does not affect the NOOBS boot menu.

[Here's an image of my keyboard layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FzRB.jpg) - it's a cheapie Logitech wireless mouse/keyboard combo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that pressing `\` (backslash) key produces the `#` character which is sufficient to enable editing the config file.  (Don't ask me how to type backslash...)

Comment: What kind of keyboard do you have? What language model?

Comment: @Bex added picture to my question.  The teensy pipe/backslash key above the Enter does make the `#`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a picture of the standard UK keyboard layout with the Pound sign over the '3' key:

[image]

This should help you locate the # sign and any other keys you'd need. Note that the key with the ~ and the # sign is often located next to the [ and ] keys on the row above its pictured location.

Comment: Well this explains why I couldn't pipe anything until I reconfigured the keyboard!  Don't these people understand where I live ?!? ;)

Comment: Right - the backslash and pipe key does not exist on standard US keyboards. Phantom key. Perhaps the old alt+092 (backslash) and alt+124 (pipe) tricks work?

Comment: alt-codes don't appear to work at the NOOBS boot menu (not on my keyboard anyway), tried with num lock on and off .  But neither pipe nor backslash are needed there.

Answer (score 0):

I  have Logitech KB and I had change to the from the default "gb" to "us" in /etc/defaults/keyboard. The default is the British keyboard.

This video calls it the pound key.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L1F-TxTPyiM

Answer (score 0):

you can write '#' by going to raspbian terminal and write comand
"sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard" the change keyboard to 'us' or 'en'
and save setting by ctrl+o and exit by ctrl+x
and then reboot and try.

Answer (score -1):

This can be inserted by using SHIFT and (backslash)

if u don't have backslsh...press ALT and the 092..

Comment: There is no reason why this answer should be written in all capital letters, please reformat it. Since you are new here I strongly suggest you take the [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour).